# How to add a column to "link" lines to polygons (Qgis)?

Tags: qgis, polygon, intersection, line, crossing

First i'll show you this image [image: SHAPES]

The green polygons are lots/land/property of different people of my city.
The blue lines are the river banks of a river that crosses my city.
The red lines are called here as "Estacas"...  in english they can be translated as "poles".

What are these poles. They are lines that  measure the distance of a construction (like a house) to the river bank.

What I have to do now is link, somehow, these poles to the lots.... each lot have an ID and each pole also have an ID. But there is lots of poles per lot. Like, the first lot, right-to-left, has seven poles crossing it. So, these seven poles, and only them, have to be linked to that one lot. (and so on to with the other lots and other rivers on my city)

Can I do that?
There's a way, with Qgis, to do it?

Comment: Sounds like a simple enough intersection or spatial join. are you trying to find the lot for the end of the line only, or the whole "pole"? as some poles cross several lots

Comment: For the end of the pole.

Comment: I thought that I could do something like, ha.... create a point, at the end of each "pole" (which would be in touch with just one "lot"), then, link the point with the lot, link the point with the pole and FINALLY link the lot with the pole using the dots "ids"....

I just don't know how to do it., hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question and comment, I've reproduced your topology. here's one way you can do it:

[image]

**Step 1:** Convert the lines to points using the Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Extract Nodes. This will create a point layer with 2 point for each line segment, one at the start and one at the end, which retain the tabular data, including the pole ID.

[image]

**Step 2:** Select the points on the side far from the river, either by a spatial selection, or manually

[image]

**Step 3**: Intersect the endpoints with the polygon plots. This will create a new point layer where each point has the attributes of the Poles AND the Plots

**Step 4:** Joint the original Poles line layer with the new intersected layer, based on pole unique ID field. This will append the plot ID to the pole ID.

**Step 5:** save as a new layer or perform summarization, depending on your need